# Async Await not waiting for execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, async-await

Part of my app uses `decSubPassword` to update state `subPassword` and then passes this state to function `changePassword`, which changes state in other context. I set sendData to run on button press. When I press button once, by analyzing logs I can see that subPassword hasn't changed which means, that decSubPassword function didn't update my state. However, when I press button second time (in short time) state instanly updates. That suggests to me, that there are some syncing problems and that application doesn't wait until `decSubPassword` is executed. I tried to make `sendData` function async and added await to `decSubPassword` as below, but it didn't solve my problem.

```
  const sendData = async (id) => {
    await decSubPassword({ id, secretKey });
    changePassword(subPassword);

    changeId(id);
    changeUsername(username);
    changeDomain(domain);
    changeDescription(description);

    console.log({ subPassword });
    console.log(subPassword);
  };
```

decSubPassword function

```
const decSubPassword = (dispatch) => async ({ id, secretKey }) => {
  const response = await trackerApi.get("/api/password/" + id + "/");
  const responsePassword = response.data.password;
  const decPassword = decryptRecord(responsePassword, secretKey);
  dispatch({ type: "dec_sub_password", payload: decPassword });
};
```

Comment: `decSubPassword` is not an async function. You defined it as `decSubPassword = (dispatch) => async ({ id, secretKey }) => { ... }`, i.e. a _regular_ function that _returns_ an async function, so `await decSubPassword()` has nothing it needs to wait for. Maybe try `decSubPassword = async ({ id, secretKey }) => { ... }`?

Comment: You mixed up your [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), it should be: `const thunkAction = (args) => async (dispatch,getState)=>` so `const decSubPassword = ({ id, secretKey }) => async (dispatch)`. Not sure how you dispatch decSubPassword from component, are you using connect or useDispatch and why is that code missing from your question?